# Implicit link to title using different link text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm aware that you can link to a header on the same page using:

```
Link to header: `This is a Header`_

This is a Header
================
```

But is it possible to choose what text is used for the link? Something like:

```
`Cheese <This is a Header>`_
```

I was hoping that could be done to display the text "Cheese" as a link to the header, i.e. [Cheese](http://google.com) instead of [This is a Header](http://google.com).

Is there any way to do that? Or will an implied header link always have the header itself as the text shown?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible since Docutils 0.11.

Your example `Cheese <This is a Header>`_, will not work, because Docutils will interpret `This is a Header` as an *external* hyperlink target (i.e. an URL).

To make it work, you need to mark the hyperlink target as internal by appending an underscore:

```
`Cheese <This is a Header_>`_
```

Note the two underscores: One for the link target, and one for the link itself.

For more details, refer to the [Docutils documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#id84).